# postgres bulk data type change

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, timestamp, database-migration

I needed to change all tables columns in the whole DB from data type `timestamp`**`without`**`time zone` to `timestamp(0)`**`with`**`time zone`.
So I created this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grd_replace_datetime_with_timezone()
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
  old_column RECORD;  
    s text;
BEGIN

FOR old_column IN (
    SELECT
        isc.table_schema as table_schema,
        isc.table_name as table_name,
        isc.column_name as column_name
    FROM 
        information_schema.columns  isc
    INNER JOIN 
        pg_tables pt
            ON (isc.table_schema = pt.schemaname and isc.table_name = pt.tablename)
    WHERE
        isc.column_name like '%date%' and 
        isc.table_schema in ('public') and 
        isc.data_type = 'timestamp without time zone'
    ORDER BY
        isc.table_name ASC
    ) 
LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Schema: %',old_column.table_schema;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Table: %',old_column.table_name;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Column %',old_column.column_name;


    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE '||old_column.table_schema||'.'||old_column.table_name||'
                ALTER COLUMN '||old_column.column_name||' TYPE timestamp(0) with time zone';

    RAISE NOTICE '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------';
    RAISE NOTICE '';
END LOOP;


RETURN 'S';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

But some views depend on affected columns and I got error:

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule
> ```

Also I got error about indexes.

How to change the data type for all `timestamp without time zone` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no built-in way to auto-change depending views when the datatype changes.
I see two possibilities:

1. **`DROP`** all depending views before the type change and **recreate** them afterwards.
2. A completely different approach: **Dump** the database, change the table definition in the dump and **restore** it. As long as you do that **in the same time zone**, `timestamp without time zone` should be coerced to `timestamptz(0)` correctly. Note that the cast to `timestamptz(0)` **rounds** to full seconds.

If you have more than a handful of objects, dump & restore is the way to go - if you can afford the downtime.

#### Demo

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t  (id int, x timestamp);
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 (id int, x timestamptz(0);

INSERT INTO t VALUES
 (1, '2019-05-25 13:23:03.123')  -- rounds down
 (1, '2019-05-25 13:23:03.987')  -- rounds up
,(2, '2019-05-25 23:23:03')
,(3, '2019-05-25 0:0:0');

COPY t  TO   '/var/lib/postgres/ts_test.sql';
COPY t1 FROM '/var/lib/postgres/ts_test.sql';

SELECT t.x, t.x::timestamptz(0), t1.x
FROM   t
JOIN   t1 USING (id);
```

Coercion happens automatically and correctly.

Related:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: IMHO dump+edit+restore is the only sane thing to do. Besides views/rules, there are also references that are "invisible" to the schema, such as functions and triggers. And: having separate --schema-only and --data-only dumps, editing is no more than a sed-job.

Comment: @wildplasser: I agree, for more than a hand full of objects, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with pg_dump

first make a dump with --format=plain --schema-only

Change the data-type in the dump file and restore it in  a new db.

Than you make a dump with --data-only and restore them in the new db.